# ¿Es correcto responder preguntas de programación basadas en matemáticas?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Muchas veces, respondiendo preguntas basadas en matemáticas, y algoritmia, he recibido comentarios como:

- "Esta respuesta está basada en opiniones personales"
- "No se ajusta al contenido de StackOverflow"
- etc...

Realmente pienso que estos comentarios, en parte, son ciertos, puesto cuando te hacen una pregunta del tipo:

> "Tengo esta red neuronal, mis resultados no convergen, ¿Qué puedo
> hacer?"

No hay para esto una solución concreta (en muchos casos). Puede que tenga que limpiar los datos, que tenga las clases desbalanceadas, que la estructura de la red neuronal no sea la optima, funciones que podrían ser mejor, etc. **Pero no hay una respuesta concisa**, lo que se puede responder es una serie de soluciones que ayudarán (otras no) a mejorar la red neuronal, en resumen, acotar y guiar en el camino al OP.

Esto sucede porque en análisis de datos, no siempre hay una solución exacta a tu problema, tienes que iterar y probar varias hipotesis. Y lo que funciona para un conjunto de datos, puede no funcionar para otro.

He visto en el SO en inglés, que sí se suelen responder estas preguntas (a pesar de tener comunidades específicas para esto como "cross validated", "Data Science", etc). Pero también es cierto que nosotros tenemos que crear nuestra propia comunidad.

En resumen, **¿Es correcto responder estas preguntas?**

Pongo ejemplos de preguntas en las que me ha pasado esto, para que se entienda mejor:

- [Ayuda para entrenar un modelo de red neuronal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/312602/ayuda-para-entrenar-un-modelo-de-red-neuronal/313090#313090)
- [Entrenar red neuronal(Dudas)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287137/entrenar-red-neuronaldudas/287438#287438)
- [¿Son las redes bayesianas un tipo de red Neuronal? [cerrada]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298508/son-las-redes-bayesianas-un-tipo-de-red-neuronal/298889#298889)
- [¿Por qué la matriz de confusión siempre sale de esta forma?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359234/por-qu%c3%a9-la-matriz-de-confusi%c3%b3n-siempre-sale-de-esta-forma/359371#359371)

### Actualización

A pesar de los ejemplos, no tienen porque ser solo preguntas de Deep Learning (redes neuronales), también me refiero a otros algoritmos de Machine Learning más cómunes, (regresión lineal, regresión logística, árboles de decisión, etc.) Y **algoritmia en general.**

Comment: También sería interesante en el caso de que no se deban responder, si se debería crear una comunidad para este tipo de preguntas como existen en el SO en inglés.

Comment: La primer pregunta incluída como ejemplo tiene un puntuación de +6 y está marcada como aceptada y no tiene comentarios como los mencionados en este post. Si recibiste en esa un pregunta un comentario como los mencionados ya fue eleminado y por lo tanto no veo sentido incluirlo como ejemplo para esta pregunta.

Comment: En relación a crear nuevas comunidades internacionales según entiendo eso está detenido hasta nuevo aviso. El mejor lugar para revisar el estado actual de eso es en [meta.se] aunque seguramente cuando cambie se notificará aquí también.

Comment: Realmente ahí quiero mostrar la final linea que hay, en este tipo de preguntas. Tiene +6 pero yo directamente, **no soluciono nada** (por lo comentado, de que no es posible dar una solución concreta), doy varias maneras de hacer funcionar su generador de imagenes lo mejor posible, y explico la diferencia entre la función de error y la métrica de accuracy (algo puramente matemático).  Respecto a lo de la comunidad, tenía entendido que tenía que ver con "Area 51", pero no estoy muy puesto en ese tema. Muchas gracias por la info!

Comment: .......         42         ......

Answer (score 3):

Aquí hay dos vertientes en mi opinión.

Por un lado está la temática, donde podemos discutir si preguntas sobre redes neuronales que están mas inclinadas a las matemáticas que a la programación son pertinentes en el sitio (avanzo que mi opinión es que no entran en la temática del sitio, pero esa es mi opinión, es la comunidad la que debe decidirlo).

Por otro lado está la cuestión de las preguntas en concreto. En el sitio se pide que las preguntas sean concretas, específicas sobre un problema en concreto con el que nos estamos encontrando. Analizando las preguntas que pones como ejemplo, la única que está cerrada es [¿Son las redes bayesianas un tipo de red Neuronal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/298508/15301) y la razón es que es una pregunta un poco genérica sobre un tema teórico. En este caso, el problema no es la temática sino la pregunta en si, y en mi opinión también está correctamente cerrada.

Comment: Buena disección! Sí, sin duda en la primera parte de la temática, yo creo que es donde hay más confusión. También he hecho una actualización de la pregunta, porque me refería en general a todo lo relaccionado con la algoritmia y la programación, y con los ejemplos se puede malinterpretar.

Answer (score 2):

No creo correcto plantear problemas matemáticos. Este es un sitio de programación; toda pregunta debe ser formulada en términos de código, sintaxis, operaciones permitidas, etc.

Tomo como ejemplo [¿Cómo hacer una regresión en una serie temporal de vectores?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/402870/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-una-regresi%c3%b3n-en-una-serie-temporal-de-vectores).

Para poder responderla, debería dominar un área de conocimiento ajeno a la programación. ¿Qué es una serie temporal de vectores? ¿Qué es una regresión? ¿Es una operación válida para el juego de datos que se presenta? ¿Quiere que le explique como se hace?

En este ejemplo lo que en realidad está preguntando por errores de programación que nada tienen que ver con series temporales:

- ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
- TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Eso si puede ser respondido. De hecho, ha sido preguntado y respondido más de una vez.

La pregunta, originalmente matemática, puede ser reformulada como un problema de programación puro.